# Visual Studio Code Quick Constructor for Dart not working

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I created this Dart Class in Visual Studio Code:

```dart
class User {
  String userId;
  String info;
}
```

`Ctrl` + `.` not opening the `quick fix` menu for a quick constructor.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to show all of the quick-fix options? like this -

[image]

Comment: That functionality doesn't come from the official Dart extension, it seems to come from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator - do you have that installed?

Answer (score 14):

Add this extension on visual studio code [Dart Data Class Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotup.dart-data-class-generator). Execute on vscode *ctrl + p* and paste *ext install BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator*

[image: installing "ext install BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator"]
[image: execute "ctrl + ."]

Comment: The link is dead, updated one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotup.dart-data-class-generator

Comment: Hi, the link is actually online

Comment: but it is dead now, please update with the link provided above

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem; The extension is installed but I still only have 'Convert class to a mixin'.

Edit: I restarted VSCode and the extension started to work. You may also need to clear workspace cache.

Comment: Same, I had to restart and it shows up in the quick fix options. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

That feature does not derive from the official Dart library extension,
You should install this extension from Visual studio marketplace :
[from this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotup.dart-data-class-generator)

if installed then try `Ctrl + .` within class and select Generate constructor.

you can follow below numbers to quick fix the

1. Create a class with properties.
2. Place your cursor on the first line
   of the class, the constructor or a field.
3. Hit CTRL + . to open the
   quick fix dialog.
4. Choose one of the available options.
5. If extension won't work, then you may restart the VS Code.

Comment: The link is dead, updated one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotup.dart-data-class-generator

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl` + `.` doesn't work for me whenever there is a constructor in the class.

When a constructor exists,  `Ctrl` + `.`  returns **No code actions available**

**Solution:**
comment out any constructor(s)

Then it works as intended, i.e. `Ctrl` + `.` on class field displays a pop-up menu to auto-generate class methods, e.g. a constructor, JSON serialisation, toString, copyWith, etc

Remember to uncomment the constructor when you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the cache did the job. I used this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MamoruDS.workspace-cacheclean) to clear the cache of the workspace and restart.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the Dart Data Class Generator extension in VS. you can use this link : [Dart Data Class Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hzgood.dart-data-class-generator) , restart the VS after you install the extension.

Answer (score -1):

Name: Dart Data Class Generator
Id: dotup.dart-data-class-generator
Description: Create dart data classes easily, fast and without writing boilerplate or running code generation.
Version: 0.5.3
Publisher: dotup
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotup.dart-data-class-generator

I have tried this extension and its auto-generating constructor and other features by ctrl + . keyboard shortcut. But please after installing this extension try to restart your IDE(VS code).